# Почему в php нет crc16

Tags: php, функции

Почему в php нет функции для вычисления `crc16`, но есть `crc32` ?
Про то что можно использовать сдвиги `'>>'` уже выяснил.
Но всё же.

**UPD**
Меня волнует почему? А не как сделать.

Comment: А почему crc16 должна быть в стандартной библиотеке PHP? C, Basic, Perl, или какого-то другого языка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В 1993—2004 годах Koopman, Castagnoli
> и другие исследовали пространство
> полиномов разрядности до 16, 24 и 32
> битов, найдя полиномы, дающие лучшую
> производительность (в смысле кодового
> расстояния), чем полиномы из
> существующих протоколов, и
> опубликовали лучшие из них с целью
> улучшения качества функций обнаружения
> ошибок в будущих стандартах
>
> Самым популярным и рекомендуемым IEEE полиномом стал CRC-32

Скорее всего из-за этого. [пруф](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Циклический_избыточный_код#.)